# From where did the program gets json_myobj in this program

Tags: python, json

I am following this tutorial

http://pymotw.com/2/json/index.html#working-with-your-own-types

He has this code

```
import json
import json_myobj

obj = json_myobj.MyObj('instance value goes here')
```

I am not able to find from where did he gets `json_myobj`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MODULE: <module 'json_myobj' from '/Users/dhellmann/Documents/PyMOTW/src/PyMOTW/json/json_myobj.pyc'>
```

Comment: why don't he mention its content on the tutorial. i want to know what it does

Comment: I don't know why he omitted that. But you can just grab it from here. http://code.doughellmann.com/py_stdlib_by_example/src/d6b6c855cced/PyMOTW/json/json_myobj.py

Answer (score 0):

MODULE:  CLASS:

He is using json_myobj as customized json object. and converting it to other object of his own.

Answer (score 0):

He has made a short cut, missing out the creation of the object. In the following example, I have included my own class 'Car', with an instance 'my_car'

```
import json


class Car(object):
    def __init__(self, make="", model=""):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model


class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self, s):
        self.s = s
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<MyObj(%s)>' % self.s

my_car = Car("BMW", "320d")
obj = MyObj(my_car)

print 'First attempt'
try:
    print json.dumps(obj)
except TypeError, err:
    print 'ERROR:', err

def convert_to_builtin_type(obj):
    print 'default(', repr(obj), ')'
    # Convert objects to a dictionary of their representation
    d = { '__class__':obj.__class__.__name__,
          '__module__':obj.__module__,
          }
    d.update(obj.__dict__)
    return d

print
print 'With default'
print json.dumps(obj, default=convert_to_builtin_type)
```